# Lock a row in database and release it later

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, locking

I have the following use case -

1. User registers and fills the details in a form. User data is stored in the DB under a table say 'user'.
2. Admins logs into the application. Verify the user data and enables the user.

The ask here is to lock the user data from any further update or delete operations and only allow read operations. We release the lock on the user data only when the user details are approved by the admin.

I explored spring boot pessimistic locking. However, it doesn't fit the use case above since I will allow locking and releasing under one transaction. Do we have any feature under spring boot to lock a table's row and then release it later?

Or is there a way to implement a workflow process using spring boot?

Answer (score 1):

Pessimistic and Optimistic locks are used to prevent concurrent updates from transactions are running simultaneous.

It is not your case at all.

1. You can create a user in a separate table and copy it to the main table after the approval.
2. Just add a flag column to the User and don't allow updates if flag `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the community project [Spring Content](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content).

This project contains a module called [Spring Versions JPA](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.paulcwarren/spring-versions-jpa/1.1.0.M3) that allows you to add the locking and versioning semantics to your JPA Entity's that you describe.  This is a very common use case in content management applications (that Spring Content is designed to serve).  You can read more about it [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/1.1.0.M3/jpaversions-index.html).

It was designed as a distinct module that could be used separately from the main Spring Content project but I have no idea if anyone has actually used it this way so YMMV.  That said, I'd be happy to provide help getting you up and running if you raise Issues on our github project.  It is *probably* easier than writing this logic yourself.